# How to draw the conclusion that $f$ is continuous?

Tags: differential-topology

Given $X$ is compact and $Y$ connected, and $f$ is a submersion.

How to draw the conclusion that $f$ is continuous?

In my book, submersion is defined as:

[image]

Comment: Usually the term "submersion" only refers to a map that is $C^k$ for some $k$, and hence already continuous. What is your definition of "submersion"?

Comment: Thanks a lot @ZevChonoles, please see the update. =)

Comment: That doesn't really address my concern - how is the derivative defined if the map $f$ is not at least $C^1$, and hence *already continuous*?

Comment: May I grant the assumption that $f$ is $\mathcal{C}^1$ continuous since it is talking about first-order derivative?

Comment: That is entirely reasonable to me - but that then raises the issue of what the question could possibly be intended to mean?

Comment: Yeah, I know the definition does not address your concern. But I tried to dig out the information that $\mathcal{C}^k$ differentiable, and the definition is what I found out..

Comment: Oh, I was not sure if I can grant $\mathcal{C}^1$ differentiable. Thanks @Zev.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A function that is differentiable at $x$ is continuous at $x$ (proved in Euclidean case in any textbook on real analysis; the extension to manifolds uses the fact that chart maps are homeomorphisms).

Therefore, a function for which $df_x$ exists at every point is continuous at every point. The surjectivity of $df_x$ is not needed to obtain the continuity of $f$.

Comment: Thank you, the great 40 votes!